# Table relation in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in Zend Framework 1. I have a project where I got table `$_referenceMap, $_dependentTables`. I am not understanding these things.

Here, `toDb` is a function that I think is related to this relational database.

Is their any way to call a function automatically with this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Model_DbTable_students extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{protected $_name = 'students';
}
public class Model_DbTable_Course extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{protected $_name = 'courses';
}
public class Model_DbTable_StudentCourse extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'student_courses';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Video' => array(
            'columns' => 'student_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Model_DbTable_Students',
            'refColumns' => 'id'
        ),
        'Tag' => array(
            'columns' => 'course_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Model_DbTable_Courses',
            'refColumns' => 'id'
        )
    );
}
```